# Google Places Details Suite/Unit Number

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm looking at the address_components of place (details) and this (for example)
is the formatted_address:

**VHT, Inc. - 9500 Bryn Mawr Avenue #650, Rosemont, IL, United States**

but no component of the address_components has the "#650".

is this a bug?

for this example there are 7 address_components: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the detail in the formatted_address, I would expect to see that value in the address_components with type room or subpremise.  But whether this is a bug or simply a currently unsupported feature, I don't know.  At the very least, you could submit a feature request asking to make sure that these types of values are included in address_components when available.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: thanks for the response.  i've created an issue for this: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5587